# Generic Select method with Databinding to ObjectDataSource?

Tags: .net, generics, data-binding, entity, objectdatasource

This is kind of a hypothetical situation at the moment but I'm wondering if it's possible.

If I had a method like this:

```
public List<T> SelectEntitiesWithWhere<T>(Func<T, bool> where) where T : EntityObject
{
    return this.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(where).ToList();
}
```

Would it be possible to call that method in a DataBound ObjectDataSource?
Possibly some code like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MyODS" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="MyProgram.EntityFramework.MyEntity"
SelectMethod="SelectEntityWithWhere" TypeName="MyProgram.BusinessLayer.MyCode">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="where" Direction="Input" DefaultValue="t => t.SomeContactId == contactId" />
</SelectParameters>
```

I know that isn't exactly how it would be, but is there some solution to this problem?  If custom code was involved, what would it take?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be able to solve part of the problem by shifting the 'genericity' from the method to the class level - according to [this information](http://forums.asp.net/t/1663075.aspx/1). But that still doesn't solve the problem of your DefaultValue requirement.

TLDR: What you want isn't possible.